# Rule error in Grakn: "rule does not form a valid clause, as it contains a multi-atom head"

Tags: rule-engine, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have a rule that is failing to commit. This is the rule:

```
when {
    $t isa person; 
    $car isa car; 
    $t2 isa person; 
    $r ($t, $car) isa ownership;     
    $r2 ($t2, $car) isa ownership;     
}, then {
    $car has age 23; 
    ($car, $t2) isa ownership; 
};
```

This is the error that I get after I `commit` this:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: InvalidKBException-A structural validation error has occurred. Please correct the [`1`] errors found. 
The rule [rule-32] does not form a valid clause, as it contains a multi-atom head
. Please check server logs for the stack trace.
All uncommitted data is cleared
```

Answer (score 1):

A rule can only infer one fact:

> In Graql, the “when” part of the rule is required to be a conjunctive
> pattern, whereas the “then” should be atomic - each rule can derive a
> single fact only

[docs](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/schema/rules)

Answer (score 0):

What @Jon T said is correct, and therefore the solution specific to your problem is to split the rule into two rules.

Both rules will have an identical `when` clause where the `then` clause has exactly one conclusion:

```
when {
    $t isa person; 
    $car isa car; 
    $t2 isa person; 
    $r ($t, $car) isa ownership;     
    $r2 ($t2, $car) isa ownership;     
}, then {
    $car has age 23; 
};

when {
    $t isa person; 
    $car isa car; 
    $t2 isa person; 
    $r ($t, $car) isa ownership;     
    $r2 ($t2, $car) isa ownership;     
}, then {
    ($car, $t2) isa ownership; 
};
```